# FineUploader - Error with JSON Response - "Response does not include the base64 encoded policy!"

Tags: json, encoding, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am trying to use FineUploader in an asp.NET MVC5 application.  When I try to upload a file using FineUploader, in my Controller, I am Base64 encoding the policy document, signing the base 64 encoded document, and then returning the results as a JSON object as per the documentation.  However, I am receiving the following error on my page after the Controller returns the JSON:

"Response does not include the base64 encoded policy!"

There must be something wrong with the formatting of my JSON payload.  Here the relative portion of code:

```
byte[] byteArrayPolicy = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonStringFull);
        string base64Policy = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArrayPolicy);

        var signature = kha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64Policy));
        var signatureString = ToHexString(signature, true);

        string  payloadString = @"{ ""policy"":""" + base64Policy + @"""," + @"""signature"":""" + signatureString + @"""}";

        JsonResult jsonRequest = Json(payloadString);

        return jsonRequest;
```

Is there anything wrong with formatting of the JSON object I am returning?  The policy is an exact copy of the policy I received from FineUploader, only it has been Base64 encoded.  The signature is a hex string.  Here is a sample of what payload looks like:

```
"{ \"policy\":\"eyJleH...=\",\"signature\":\"da186a017b038382e2cc21dfa4f1fbf806c51adf92984a9b95f1aa845aeb72e4\"}"
```

Note the "..." in the Base64 policy was for brevity.

The error I am getting says the Response does not include a Base64 encoded policy, but it appears to me that it does include the Base64 encoded policy.  Is it possible my signature is incorrect? Should it not be converted to a hex string after I compute the signature as a byte array?

Here is the actual paypload, according to Chrome:

```
"{ \"policy\":\"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\",\"signature\":\"c592b3bca0dedba10301e06df37760cb527ac0a83112ae9b668dce00f0b23465\"}"
```

Comment: I am not able to determine why it is not valid JSON.  It is in the format specified in the documentation as far as I can tell. - http://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error *does* appear to be in your code. The response payload, as you have illustrated in your answer, is this:

```
"{...}"
```

But it should be this:

```
{...}
```

After running *your* response through `JSON.parse`, the result is a single string instead of an object.

Comment: Perfect.  For anybody trying this in an asp.NET application, the reason the response was being returned as a JSON wrapped in a string, instead of just the JSON object, seems to be because I was returning a JsonResult.  FineUploader will not accept a JsonResult object, because it wraps it in quotes.  If you set your Controller return type to "string" instead of "JsonResult", then FineUploader will parse the string as JSON object.

Comment: Just a note that this issue really has nothing to do with Fine Uploader, even though you are experiencing this issue with your Fine Uploader instance. `JSON.parse`, which Fine Uploader uses to parse incoming JSON response data, is a part of the web API. Any other library that needs to parse JSON data would use the same call.